# How do I add several rows to a table in one insert, tracking the count as I go?

Tags: mysql

Without writing a stored procedure loop, is it possible to insert into a table 100 times setting some column's value to whatever iteration it's at within the "loop" (1-100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap hack:

```
select @val := 1;

insert into yourtable (valfield) select (@val := @val + 1) from any_existing_table where @val < 100;
```

[edit]
Mark, 
I edited your answer so that I could mark it as correct.
-Dr.D
[end edit]

Comment: oy vey! There MUST be a better way! :)

Comment: with a little adjustment, this now does exactly what I was hoping for!